# How to subscribe to a ContentDocument using API?

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, content, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to develop a Custom UI for subscribing ContentDocument and found out that we have ContentSubscriptionObject which stores subscription information of the document.
However we cannot insert record in this object.

Could anyone help about how can we subscribe a contentdocument through API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in a similar situation, but I had to move away from using that ContentDocumentSubscription object where is not possible to create records.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentsubscription.htm

Instead I'm using the EntitySubscription.
You can still use it to relate the user to a contentDocument and mimic the "follow" functionality.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm

I wouldn't consider this a solution but more an idea, since I don't know your requirements, but I hope it helps.